# Partitioning/Grouping/listing over data that have already been partitioned with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made a TSQL script that pretty much takes/filters sets of data from a DB(multiple tables) and dump it on other table on a different DB. So far so good.

This is how the script looks like:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATETIME = '2022-01-26 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @FechaFin DATETIME = '2022-02-25 23:59:00.000'

WHILE (@FechaInicio <= @FechaFin)
BEGIN
    PRINT '
    ;WITH CTE_CORTES AS (
        SELECT
            XX.PACIENTE_nVECES_REPETIDOS,
            XX.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO,
            XX.UNIDAD_TRATANTE,
            XX.ApellidoPaterno,
            XX.ApellidoMaterno,
            XX.NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE,
            XX.NSS,
            XX.CLAVE_CPIM,
            XX.AGREGADO_MEDICO,
            XX.TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO,
            XX.MODALIDAD,
            XX.INTERPRETACION,
            XX.PARTICION_UID
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WW.UIDESTUDIO ORDER BY WW.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO) AS PARTICION_UID
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (SUBSTRING(R.NSS,1,10)) ORDER BY R.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO) AS PACIENTE_nVECES_REPETIDOS,
                        R.UIDESTUDIO,
                        R.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO,
                        R.UNIDAD_TRATANTE,
                        R.ApellidoPaterno,
                        R.ApellidoMaterno,
                        R.NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE,
                        R.NSS,
                        R.CLAVE_CPIM,
                        R.AGREGADO_MEDICO,
                        R.TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO,
                        R.MODALIDAD,
                        CASE
                            WHEN R.RESULTADO IS NULL
                                THEN ''SIN INTERPRETACION''
                            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RESULTADO, 103)
                        END AS INTERPRETACION
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                COUNT(T.UIDESTUDIO) AS VECES_REPETIDO,
                                *
                            FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FECHAESTUDIO) AS CONSECUTIVO,
                                    E.IdPaciente,
                                    E.FOLIO AS UIDESTUDIO,
                                    CAST (E.FechaEstudio AS smalldatetime) AS FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO,
                                    ''HGZ 98'' AS UNIDAD_TRATANTE,
                                    P.ApellidoPaterno,
                                    P.ApellidoMaterno,
                                    CONCAT(P.PrimerNombre,'' '' /*COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI*/, P.SegundoNombre) AS NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE,
                                    NSS = left(P.Folio + replicate(''0'', 10), 10),
                                    CASE    
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''CR''
                                            THEN ''80.15.001''      
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''DX''
                                            THEN ''80.15.001''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''MG''
                                            THEN ''80.15.002''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''BDUS'' OR E.Modalidades=''BMD''
                                            THEN ''80.15.003''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''RF''
                                            THEN ''80.15.004''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades= ''US''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE 
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%DOPPLER%'' /*OR E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%DOPLER%''*/ THEN ''80.15.005''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion  LIKE ''%DOPPLER%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%DOPLER%'' THEN ''80.15.006''
                                                        ELSE ''80.15.005''
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades= ''CT''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE    
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%CONTRAST%'' THEN ''80.15.007''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion LIKE ''%CONTRASTADO%'' /*OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%GADOLIN%''*/ THEN ''80.15.008''
                                                        ELSE ''80.15.007''
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''MR''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE    
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%CONTRASTADO%'' OR E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%GADOLIN%'' THEN ''80.15.009''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion  LIKE ''%CONTRAST%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%GADOLIN%'' THEN ''80.15.010''
                                                        ELSE ''80.15.009''
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''XA''
                                            THEN ''80.15.011''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades = ''ES''
                                            THEN ''80.15.012''
                                        ELSE ''80.15.014''
                                    END AS CLAVE_CPIM,
                                    AGREGADO_MEDICO = LEFT(SUBSTRING(P.Folio,11,18) + REPLICATE(''0'',8),8),
                                    CASE    
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''CR''
                                            THEN ''Radiología Simple''                  
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''DX''
                                            THEN ''Radiología Simple''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''MG''
                                            THEN ''Mastografía''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''BDUS'' OR E.Modalidades=''BMD''
                                            THEN ''Densitometría''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''RF''
                                            THEN ''Radiología Contrastada''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''US''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%DOPPLER%'' /*OR E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%DOPLER%''*/ THEN ''Ultrasonido''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion LIKE ''%DOPPLER%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%DOPLER%'' THEN ''Ultrasonido Doppler''
                                                        ELSE ''Ultrasonido''
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''CT''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%CONTRAST%'' THEN ''Tomografía Computada Simple''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion  LIKE ''%CON CONTRASTE%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%CONTRASTADO%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%CONTRASTADA%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%GADOLIN%'' THEN ''Tomografía Computada con medio de Contraste''
                                                        ELSE ''Tomografía Computada Simple''                                
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''MR''
                                            THEN    (
                                                        CASE
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion NOT LIKE ''%CONTRAST%'' THEN ''Resonancia Magnética Simple''
                                                            WHEN E.Descripcion  LIKE ''%CON CONTRAST%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%CONTRASTADO%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%CONTRASTADA%'' OR E.Descripcion LIKE ''%GADOLIN%'' THEN ''Resonancia Magnética Contrastada''
                                                        ELSE ''Resonancia Magnética Simple''
                                            END     )
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''XA''
                                            THEN ''RADIOLOGIA INTERVENCIONISTA VASCULAR''
                                        WHEN E.Modalidades=''ES''
                                            THEN ''RADIOLOGIA INTERVENCIONISTA NO VASCULAR''
                                        ELSE ''OTRAS MODALIDADES DICOM''
                                    END AS TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO,
                                    E.Modalidades AS MODALIDAD,
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN I_R_E.IdEstadoResultado IN (0,1,2)
                                            THEN ''SIN INTERPRETACION''
                                        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,I_R_E.FechaResultado,103)
                                    END AS RESULTADO
                                FROM
                                    DBO.Pacientes AS P
                                INNER JOIN
                                    DBO.ImagenologiaEstudios AS E ON P.IDPACIENTE=E.IdPaciente
                                LEFT JOIN
                                    dbo.ImagenologiaResultadosEstudio AS I_R_E ON E.IdEstudio=I_R_E.IdEstudio AND E.IdEstudio=I_R_E.IdEstudio
                                WHERE
                                    E.FechaEstudio BETWEEN ' + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FechaInicio,121) + '''' +  ' AND ' + '''' + CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FechaInicio,23),' 23:59:59.999') + '''' +  ' AND E.VisiblePACS = 1
                        ) AS T
                        GROUP BY
                            T.IdPaciente,
                            T.UIDESTUDIO,
                            T.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO,
                            T.UNIDAD_TRATANTE,
                            T.ApellidoPaterno,
                            T.ApellidoMaterno,
                            T.NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE,
                            T.NSS,
                            T.CLAVE_CPIM,
                            T.AGREGADO_MEDICO,
                            T.TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO,
                            T.MODALIDAD,
                            T.RESULTADO
                        HAVING
                            COUNT(T.UIDESTUDIO) >= 1
                    ) AS R
            ) AS WW 
        ) AS XX
                    )
        INSERT INTO HIS_CORTES_UDDCM.dbo.CORTE_MES_EJEMPLO (
            [PACIENTE_nVECES_REPETIDOS],[FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO],[UNIDAD_TRATANTE],[ApellidoPaterno],[ApellidoMaterno],[NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE],[NSS],[CLAVE_CPIM],[AGREGADO_MEDICO],[TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO],[MODALIDAD],[INTERPRETACION],[PARTICION_UID])
        SELECT
            TOP 1000 [PACIENTE_nVECES_REPETIDOS],[FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO],[UNIDAD_TRATANTE],[ApellidoPaterno],[ApellidoMaterno],[NOMBRE_DEL_PACIENTE],[NSS],[CLAVE_CPIM],[AGREGADO_MEDICO],[TIPO_DE_ESTUDIO],[MODALIDAD],[INTERPRETACION],[PARTICION_UID]
        FROM
            CTE_CORTES
        WHERE
            CTE_CORTES.PARTICION_UID=1
        ORDER BY
            CTE_CORTES.NSS, CTE_CORTES.FECHA_DEL_ESTUDIO'
    SET @FechaInicio += 1
    PRINT '/*#######################################################################################SALTO DE DIA#######################################################################################*/'
END
```

The whole script relies on a line of code that pretty much partitions sets of data(I'm using `ROW_NUMBER` and nesting the `SUBSTRING` function) and the ordering of the IDs and date is taken cared of by the `ORDER BY` clause(which is as importat as the `ROW_NUMBER` window function).

This is the line I'm refering to:

[image]

What this does is basically takes the ID column(string) and goes up to 10 characters. If there are similarities between the first 10 characters among the ID column rows, then the `ROW_NUMBER` function groups/enumerates each row from 1 up to number of coincidences found within a single day(It cannot go beyond a day. Because if it does, data are not longer reliable. That's the reason why the script above inserts data day by day by using the `WHILE` loop).

This is how the table looks like after executing the TSQL script:

[image]

If you pay close attention to the first column and the rows highlighted in blue, you'll see the partitioning/grouping by sets I was talking about being performed. Rows and IDs have been sorted/ordered by date and ID(ascending) in an organized manner. Similarities between the IDs are being displayed in the nTIMES_ID_REPEATED column. The main focus is on the rows highlighted in blue. Those are the ones that meet the criteria I'm about to explain. The ones highlighted in yellow also meet the criteria(similarities) but cannot be taken into account since their respective REPORT_STATUS column(Date type) are empty.

Now, this is where it gets challenging(and honestly, I have no idea how to tackle this challenge). Based on the partitioning/grouping that has been done with the nTIMES_ID_REPEATED column, I've been tasked to access those rows(the ones that display 1, 2, 3, up to the last number) and perform(maybe) another window function to list them again(display them on a different column) as long as their respective REPORT_STATUS column is not empty.

This is how the desired result should look like:

[image]

Eventhough the `ROW_COUNT` together with the`SUBSTRING` function have found more matches(nTIMES_ID_REPEATED column), the rows in yellow cannot be taken into account since its REPORT_STATUS column are empty. Basically they should be ignored.

By the way, I made a dummy table and populated it with the very same challenge for those who want to give it a try at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE ( 
    nTIMES_ID_REPEATED INT,
    STUDY_DATE DATETIME,
    HOSPITAL varchar(255),
    FIRST_LAST_NAME varchar(255),
    SECOND_LAST_NAME varchar(255),
    PATIENT_NAME varchar(255),
    NSS varchar(255),
    CPIM_CODE varchar(255),
    ID_REMAINDER varchar(255),
    STUDY_TYPE varchar(255),
    MODALITY varchar(255),
    REPORT_STATUS varchar(255),
    UID_PARTITION INT

            );


INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','SANCHEZ','GONZALEZ','DANIELA YARELI ','9211929411','80.15.005','1F1992OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','SANCHEZ','GONZALEZ','DANIELA YARELI ','9211929411','80.15.005','1F1992OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','AVILA','ESPINOZA','MA DE JESUS ','9409850742','80.15.005','4F1961OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','AVILA','ESPINOZA','MA DE JESUS ','9409850742','80.15.005','4F1961OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','VELAZQUEZ','CONTRERAS','GRECIA IRLANDA ','9412972424','80.15.005','1F1997OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','VELAZQUEZ','CONTRERAS GRECIA IRLANDA',' ','9412972424','80.15.001','00000000','Radiología Simple','CR',' ',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','SANTIAGO','ARREDONDO','HANNA NIDIA ','9496811863','80.15.005','3F2008OR','Ultrasonido','US','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','SANTIAGO','ARREDONDO HANNA NIDIA',' ','9496811863','80.15.001','10000000','Radiología Simple','CR',' ',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (3,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','SANTIAGO','ARREDONDO HANNA NIDIA',' ','9496811863','80.15.007','13F2008O','Tomografía Computada Simple','CT','28/05/2022',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (1,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','PACHECO','PINEDA ISABEL',' ','9498790021','80.15.001','20000000','Radiología Simple','CR',' ',1)
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES (2,'2022/05/28','HGZ 98','PACHECO','PINEDA ISABEL',' ','9498790021','80.15.001','70000000','Radiología Simple','CR',' ',1)
```

Can it be done with window functions or do I have to tackle this problem in a different fashion?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you could just `partition by <ID>. FechaEstudio` and avoid all the looping. And  couldn't you run the `while` loop with a date parameter rather than dealing with building the dynamic script and running it separately?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but the whole code relies on two conditions. The code has to reliably do the pattern matching of the IDs(finding similarities within the firts ten characters) and has to be performed in single day and order it. I cannot perform the window function and partition by ID in a range of dates. The whole result becomes unreliable.

Comment: `partition by left(<ID>, 10), cast(FechaEstudio as date)` would accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these would both work. You might find that one performs better than the other:

```
case when report_status <> '' then
    row_number() over (
        partition by <ID>
        -- push the nulls out to the end so they don't interfere with numbering
        order by case when report_status <> '' then 0 else 1 end, <date>) end
```

Or

```
case when report_status <> '' then
    row_number() over (
        -- move the null rows into a distinct partition
        partition by <ID>, case when report_status <> '' then 1 end
        order by <date>) end
```

It seems that your column may be a `varchar(255)` rather than a `date`. Replace the null checks with whatever test is appropriate for your logic.

Comment: It's going to sound funny but I ran your code and I got the opposite result. But at the end of the day your code pointed me to the right direction(fist time I see somebody applaying IF/ELSE logic and then using window functions). I modified it slightly and ran it against the table and VOALA!(see the answer below). The thing I don't get is the downvoting of the post. I tried to be clear and to the point. I even went to the trouble of making a test table. Anyways, I'm greatful for your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alex I think the right fix would have been to change the test to `= ''` rather than using `is null` as noted at the end above. I had taken your column for a `date` type when I saw the `varchar(255)` in the sample DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Shawn's answer I modified his code slightly.

```
SELECT 
CASE    
    WHEN REPORT_STATUS=' '
        THEN ' '
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NSS order by CONSECUTIVO)
END AS ANOTHER_WF,
* 
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your `another_wf` column is going to be a `char` column because of the string output. If you tried to sort on that column the order would be: 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).